# admin specific app in django

Tags: django, django-admin, django-1.11

I'm using `Django 1.11`

I want to create an admin specific app which is only accessible by admin interface.

I want to create an app to add `country` and `state` records which can be added or edited only by Admin from `/admin`.

Also, these records can be used by any application to populate a select field in adding a record like `address`.

If I create `country` app in `mydangoapp/country` and add URL to `mydangoapp/mydangoapp/urls.py` then it can be accessed by other users too by `www.example.com/country` which I don't want.

**Where to create a model for this? Is it possible to create an admin specific app only?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every app can be used only as `admin` specific till the time you don't give a `urlpatterns` for that app to be accessed by users.

So, you just create an app, make models, register them. But don't write views, forms and urls for that app.

Comment: app has to be included in `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should do something like that in your *mydjangoapp* **urls.py**:-

```
from country import views as country_views
urlpatterns = [
              url(r'^admin/custom_prefix/country/', include('country.urls')),
              url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Make sure u enter it in this order(i.e. before the **r'^admin/'** regex) in **urlpatterns** list.
Hope this solves your issues :-)